# not working regexp detection of the -1 or positive integer number

Tags: regex, angularjs

How to detect -1 o any positive integer number?

I have tried `^(\-1)|(?!\-)\d+$` but doesn't work for me. Besides for -1 this matches as well as for all numbers smaller than -1 => -2, -11, -1534, ...

Regexp test: [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3bm78)

Regexp used in Agularjs html form: [pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/66fvhrz8Enh44MrmyInq?p=preview)

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="myData" ng-pattern="/^(\-1)|(?!\-)\d+$/">
  <div ng-if="myForm.myInput.$error.pattern" style="color:red;">
    Input does not match the regexp pattern!
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it didn't work is because you need to put brackets. Otherwise, the `|` would require either a number starting with `-1` or ending with any amount of digits, but not the two at the same time.

```
^(-1|\d+)$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/oI3lA2/3)

Comment: This expression is still valid for -1000

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky, no it is not. I updated the link to check for -1000, as you can see, it doesn't match it

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this, and it seems to work for me:

```
/^-1$|^0$|^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/
```

Plunker here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UM3UL0QWImrG82XXpKuw?p=preview

Comment: `[1-9]+[0-9]*`... really now xd